# How can I reduce my time complexity in this code?

Tags: java, time-complexity

You are given an integer array nums containing distinct numbers, and you can perform the following operations until the array is empty:

1.If the first element has the smallest value, remove it
2.Otherwise, put the first element at the end of the array.
Return an integer denoting the number of operations it takes to make nums empty.

```
class Solution {

    public int find(ArrayList<Integer> nums){
        /* To find min val in nums */
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0;i<nums.size();i++){
             min = Math.min(nums.get(i),min);
        }

        return min;
    }

    public long countOperationsToEmptyArray(int[] nums) {
        
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;   
        ArrayList<Integer>list  = new ArrayList<>();  
        /* converting nums to list*/
        for(int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){
             min = Math.min(nums[i],min);
             list.add(nums[i]);
        }
        
        long ans= 0;
        /* iterating over list till it gets empty */
        while(list.size()>0){ 
            
            if(list.get(0)==min){
                list.remove(0);
                min  = find(list);
            }else{
                int temp = list.remove(0);
                list.add(temp);
            } 
            ans++;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened to the comments? Did you retype the code instead of copy-pasting it?

Comment: Welcome! This sounds more like a [codereview.se] question. I suggest you read [The guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/267244) to see if your question fits there instead. See also [their on-topic help page](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [their ask-checklist FAQ](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1954/267244).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 1):

What you provided, was the so called "intuitive approach". To pass this task, we need to achieve a runtime complexity of `O(n*log(n))` resp. lower than `O(n^2)`!

You can see many good "solutions" (tab) of that task, but besides copy, paste and getting it done, understanding/learning/improving would be nice!

Taking the [top rated](https://leetcode.com/problems/make-array-empty/solutions/3466800/java-c-python-easy-sort-solution/):

> ```java
> public long countOperationsToEmptyArray(int[] A) {
>     Map<Integer, Integer> pos = new HashMap<>();
>     long n = A.length, res = n;
>     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
>         pos.put(A[i], i);
>     Arrays.sort(A);
>     for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
>         if (pos.get(A[i]) < pos.get(A[i - 1]))
>             res += n - i;
>     return res;
> }
> ```

, which achieves top runtime:

```txt
Runtime    66 ms, Beats      100% <= this is hard to beat (with java)
Memory   62.3 MB, Beats    28.57%
```

#### How does it work!?

- A perfectly sorted array should return `N`. We can, according to task description, delete each element right away, while a
- Descending array would be the worst case and produce `N * (N - 1)` "operations".

What can we do with that?
Instead of "doing it and counting", we can:

1. **Store the original position** of each array element. (O(n))

   > ```
   > for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   >   pos.put(A[i], i);
   > ```
2. We **efficiently sort** `A`. (Arrays.sort(), O(nlogn))

   After these steps our (un/sorted) mapping would look like:

   - `[{1,0},{2,1},{3,2}]` in "best case"
   - `[{1,2},{2,1},{3,0}]` in "worst case"
3. The final loop iterates (O(n)) and **checks** whether the current element's position is lower than previous element's position:

   > ```java
   > if (pos.get(A[i]) < pos.get(A[i - 1]))
   > ```

   which means it is "bad sorted", and increases the result by `n - i`
   , which refers to its "reversed original position" or the exact count of swaps this element has to take to get into correct position, it's "dis-tance"/"-order".

   Since `result = n` was initialized, we get for our sample:

   - `3` in "best case"
   - `3 + 2 + 1 = 6` in "worst case"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeatedly copying all of the elements, you can use a index to keep track of how to rotate the array and a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) or a sentinel value or just comparing to the new minimum to keep track of which elements are still in the set.

Comment: Replacing the `ArrayList` with an `ArrayBlockingQueue` is another way to avoid copying.